# Angular : How to manage the URL of a particular tree

Tags: angular, url, routes, nested

I have a main page of folders. Each folders contain a Todo-list, and each Todo list contains task that have their own pages. Here's the three (below).
Obviously, each folder and each task has an ID.

I'm a little bit lost how to manage parameters and nested routes with angular. I was thinking about doing like that, but I'm really not sure about this approach, so if you can help me...

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'folders', component : FoldersListComponent},
  {
    path: 'folders/:id/tasks', 
    component : TodoListComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tasks/:id',
        component: SingleTaskComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

[image: Tree]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Options

Nesting routes involves a lot more lines of code in this scenario.

Compare the readability of this block of code to your example, and the second code block I have at the bottom of this post.

```
  { path: 'folders', component : FoldersListComponent },
  { path: 'folders/:folderId', component : TodoListComponent },
  { path: 'folders/:folderId/tasks/:taskId', component : SingleTaskComponent },
```

This is a totally fine solution.
Also note that I used folderId and taskId, instead of id twice. This is because you will probably want to access those id's, and it will be a bit confusing remebering which `ActivatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'))` gets you.

---

#### Comments on your example

To complete your example, a path with children can't have a component of it's own (in reference to where you had TodoListComponent declared). Your example would have folders/3/tasks/tasks/4 route to the TodoList component like that.

Also children paths are relative to their parent, so to have the path to a task as folders/3/tasks/1/ you can just put ":id", as done below.

```
  { path: "folders", component: FoldersListComponent },
  {
    path: "folders/:id/tasks",
    children: [
      {
        path: ":id",
        component: SingleTaskComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: TodoListComponent,
      }
    ],
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll just keep your solution. Just a question from an SEO point of view: isn't it better to have in the URL "tasks" when you are in a Todo list?

Comment: Im not too familiar with SEO, but according to this https://moz.com/learn/seo/url the url is only a minor factor for search engine ranking